# drag-and-drop jquery grid plugin with multi-grid option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, grid

I am  tryng with these jquery plugins.

https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js and https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift

I want two grids in same page on which when i drag some div from one grid to another grid where second grid is fixed.say 4x4 (square or rectangular), so i should able drag only 16 divs.

how we can achieve this using  any of the above plugin.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to do it for you, or help you in your work?

Comment: i want someone to help ,i.e  give direction to achieve this. any usefull links ....